# How to catch mouse movement when left mouseButton is pressed on a button control and released on different button control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a custom user control in WPF, which is shown in attached image, I want to mouse left click on button "8" and by holding down mouse button move on another button eg: button "1" and release mouse left button. Now i want to get the both buttons "8" when clicking on it and "1" when releasing the button. I have registered the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown to get mouse down event and PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp to get mouse up event. but when i click on  "8" and move on "1" release button in both event i get the same "8" button.
Can anyone please let me know how can i achieve this.

```
private ToggleButton _startButton;
private ToggleButton _endButton;

private void tb_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  _startButton = sender as ToggleButton;
}

private void tb_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  _endButton = sender as ToggleButton;
  if (_endButton != null && _startButton != null)
  {
    string start = _startButton.Content.ToString();
    string end = _endButton.Content.ToString();
    if (!start.Equals(end))
      ToggleButton(_endButton);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour caused by the fact that the mouse is getting captured. Try using hit testing to get an element located at the point where mouse was released: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608752.aspx

**UPDATE**

In example you have the following layout:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication24.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="b1" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp_1"/>
        <Button Content="b2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

On your PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp handler you should execute the following code:

```
private void Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    var result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, e.GetPosition(this));            
}
```

Note that you should use HitTest for element that is the common parent for both your buttons (in example - it is the MainWindow)

In the result.VisualHit property you can see the element located under cursor.

After that you can use VisualTreeHelper to check if it is the child of your Button, or try the following approach:

1)Create some flag attached property:

```
public static bool GetIsHitTestTarget(DependencyObject obj) {
    return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsHitTestTargetProperty);
}
public static void SetIsHitTestTarget(DependencyObject obj, bool value) {
    obj.SetValue(IsHitTestTargetProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsHitTestTargetProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsHitTestTarget", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

2) Set it's value for the elements that you should find:

```
<Button Content="b1" local:MainWindow.IsHitTestTarget="true" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp_1"/>
<Button Content="b2" local:MainWindow.IsHitTestTarget="true"/>
```

3) Modify the PreviewLeftButtonUp callback:

```
private void Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    DependencyObject result = null;
    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this,        
        (o)=> {if(GetIsHitTestTarget(o)) {
            result = o;
            return HitTestFilterBehavior.Stop;
        }
        return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
        },
        (res) => HitTestResultBehavior.Stop,
        new PointHitTestParameters(e.GetPosition(this)));
}
```

Comment: I have added this code to my method: Point pt = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender); // Perform the hit test against a given portion of the visual object tree. HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this.Parent as Visual, pt); if (result == null) return;                                                               But i always get result value null. I have passed the parent control as visual reference parameter, i have also tried to pass the same control as Visual refence bt in both cases i got null hit result, is there any other way to get the element.

Comment: I have modified my previous answer to show you how does it works

Comment: Thanks ASerov
for your support. The code is working as desired. -:)